# manage routes in a htaccess file in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

i have this content in my routes file :

```
$route['logout']                = 'admin/logout';
$route['res_yass']              = 'page/index/res_yass';
$route['res_nesr']              = 'page/index/res_nesr';
$route['societe']               = 'page/index/societe';
$route['app_type']              = 'page/index/app_type';
$route['future_plan_situation'] = 'page/index/future_plan_situation';
$route['plan_situation']        = 'page/index/plan_situation';
$route['fini_stand']            = 'page/index/fini_stand';
$route['future_app_type']       = 'page/index/future_app_type';
```

that works fine now but whenever i want to add a page i have to add it in the routes page and that's not a good idea. so how can i change it in a htaccess file except the logout one.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$route['(:any)'] = "page/index/$1";
$route['logout'] = 'admin/logout';
```

Comment: Does not matter. Literal match has a higher priority over the regular expression.